# C++ order of operations for initializing an array size

Tags: c++

I'm trying to allocate the exact size of the array here. However I need to initialize it before I calculate the size of the array. does anyone know what I should do now?
Thanks in advance!

b.t.w I'm making a hangman game, just for fun.

```
char letters[30];

strcpy(letters, word.c_str());

int wordLen = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < letters[i]; i++){

    wordLen++;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *However I need to initialize it before I calculate the size of the array.*?  Also, do you even need an array in the first place?  a `std::string` should work.

Comment: `word` looks like it might be a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). If it is, it has a [`size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) member method which reports the string's size. In any case, you should stick with `std::string` for your string manipulation needs.

Comment: That `for` loop looks very suspect. It will loop until it finds a letter who's value is no less than it's position. Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: `i < letters[i]` does not make sense, did you mean `letters[i] != '\0'`? This is a reimplementation of `strlen`, but really, use `std::string`.

Comment: I need an array because in hangman you guess per letter. But I get that i < letters[i] does't make sense

Comment: You can access a std::string with [i] like an array.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear, what you are trying to do with that loop, and it looks very suspicious (you need to provide more information on what you are trying to do here for advise on how to fix it if necessary), but assuming it is correct your code can be fixed by eliminating that buffer  and `strcpy()` call at all:

```
int wordLen = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < word[i]; i++){
    wordLen++;
}
```

if you need a copy of variable `word` to modify, not changing original, then just create another `std::string` instance as a copy. There is no reason to create raw char array in your case.

Comment: Also the loop itself has issues.  There is nothing to say that it wont iterate of the end of the array.  If, for instance they are using ascii, then the first letter starts at 65 so `i` could easily become grater than `word.size()`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I totally agree but there is no infomation at all to understand what OP wants to do in that loop. It is very suspision and I mentioned that in my answer. Maybe I should make it more clear.

Comment: I was trying to get the size of the array, and couldn't find a better way. Do you know how I should do this? Sorry I'm not a experienced programmer...

Comment: raw array size is obtained by `sizeof()` but that is probably not what you mean. If you mean string length, then `std::string` has 2 methods - `size()` and `length()` (they do the same which one to use is your preference) and you do not need raw char array. Especially that C++ does not support variable length array.

Comment: I need the amount of individual characters in the array.

Comment: @Hidde8erberg for `char array[30]` there are 30 individual characters. Always. You can keep shorter null terminated strings in it (up to 29 letter in them) and you would need to call `strlen` to get string length at runtime. That is C programming. But again you should not do that in C++, learn how to use `std::string` properly.